# Display Value Differently in Input Field Without Changing the Value?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an application with an input field that takes a dollar value. I need to change the way this dollar value displays so that the number is formatted with a $ and commas, like $5,550.00 if the user just enters 5550.

I found a way to do this, but doing so causes all hell to break loose in the code that uses the value from this field--it does a bunch of stuff, including database updates that break if given $5,550.00 instead of 5550.

There is a TON of underlying code and I am not empowered to go fix it all. I need to figure out a way to display this value to the user as $5,550.00 but keep the underlying value as 5550.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're going to downvote me please let me know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 text inputs. A "façade" one that the user sees, and a "real" one which is actually submitted to the server with the form. When the user enters text into the visible input, you can use JavaScript to set whatever corresponding value you want into the "real" (hidden) input. That effectively decouples the displayed value from the submitted one. You can even use a plugin such as [jQuery Masked Input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) to do the front-end number formatting for you.

Make sure to only apply this when JS is enabled in the browser, otherwise your form will be broken with JS disabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about an HTML form, I would submit the form using javascript.

You could revert the value back to unformatted before submitting the form.